# How to create hex-dump .bin file from powershell or cmd?

Tags: powershell, cmd, hex, bin

The main purpose is to write hex-coded string or just hex data into a main bin file, whether or not, hex-dumped.

Using windows powershell or cmd, we're trying to create a bin file in order to concatenate it with the main one using opensource [srecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/srecord-1.64.pdf) execution scripts, like srec_cat.exe.

We've managed to hex-dump some stuff like a string or so in powershell:

"hello_world" would be:

```
PS C:\Users\user> echo hello_world | format-hex > output.bin
```

The concent of that "bin" file is:

```
           Ruta:

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   68 65 6C 6C 6F 5F 77 6F 72 6C 64                 hello_world
```

However, this output above, is string formatted, and what is needed is to dump that as a bin type file. This is because srecord's srec_cat tool needs it to be that way in order to write (concat) that data at some memory region of the main bin file that will be flashed into devices.

The output needed would be something like:

```
00000000: 68 65 6C 6C 6F 5F 77 6F 72 6C 64 00 00 00 00 00  #hello_world
```

Again, as binary type file.

Thanks a lot for your time and attention!

---

### First edit:

So, we're using Atmel Studio to make a program that will work with SAMD21 devices. Along with SAM ICE via JTAG for flashing and debugging. The result of the compilation, and hence the final executable that is mounted for debugging is a *.bin file. The encoding maybe is UTF-8.

What I'm trying to do, is to add data like IDs, keys, and so, into specific memory directions of the final firmware *.bin file in order to be flashed.

Making use of srec tools, something like this is done:

First conversion:

```
srec_cat data_input_file.bin -o data_input_file.srec
```

Second conversion:

```
srec_cat main_file.bin -binary -o main_file.srec
```

The concat at specific memory region, this command is generic (no address targeted):

```
srec_cat data_input_file.srec main_file.srec -o final_firmware.bin
```

I don't know how to create such binary file with hex-coded strings, starting at zero address, up to space needed to hold the data.

With srec tools, we're able to put that data into the directions needed.

---

### Second Edit

The sources of raw bytes that will be used are two.

The first one is the *.bin result of the Atmel Studio's compilation that is intended to be flashed into the hardware devices we're using.

The content of the file, for example would be something like, `Main_File_1.bin`:

```
00000000: 30 30 30 30 09 66 66 20 66 65 20 36 38 20 30 30  #0000.ff fe 68 00
00000010: 20 36 35 20 30 30 20 36 63 20 30 30 20 20 36 63  # 65 00 6c 00  6c
00000020: 20 30 30 20 36 66 20 30 30 20 35 66 20 30 30 20  # 00 6f 00 5f 00
00000030: 37 37 20 30 30 20 20 20 2E 2E 68 2E 65 2E 6C 2E  #77 00   ..h.e.l.
00000040: 6C 2E 6F 2E 5F 2E 77 2E 0D 0A 30 30 31 30 09 36  #l.o._.w...0010.6
00000050: 66 20 30 30 20 37 32 20 30 30 20 36 63 20 30 30  #f 00 72 00 6c 00
00000060: 20 36 34 20 30 30 20 20 30 64 20 30 30 20 30 61  # 64 00  0d 00 0a
00000070: 20 30 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  # 00
00000080: 20 20 6F 2E 72 2E 6C 2E 64 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 0D 0A  #  o.r.l.d......
```

Again, is not mandatory to be in hex-dump fashion, the hex-dump is for visual reference, I know that it can be something like, `Main_File_1.bin`:

```
X"  ¡@  @  @                              @          @  @  @  @  @  @  e)  @  @  @  @  a/  q/  /  ‘/  ¡/  ±/  @  @  @  @  @  @  @  @  @  @  @  @  @  µL#x +ÑK +ÐH à ¿##p½Ø       ,h  µK +ÐHI à ¿Hh +ÐK + Ð˜G½ÀF    ,h  Ü   ,h      µ  K˜GLú!‰  GK`ú!‰  GK`"K`½ÀFU>  E         à à0µKhJ %€!Ià ,ÐT`•`hBüÐ8öÒ0½   à àµKh + Ð˜G½ÀFô   pµ‚° #J`¬%ep£p%p& !N°G% !°G' !°GK !Ya@"ZaYaZaKhBÐ
KhšÔ    K˜G"Kp¿ó_b¶  °p½ô   å*  €D Aà à     8µ (ÐM ¨G< ,úÑ8½ÀFM  µL #£a K˜G@#£a½€D A  µ„°K`¬ 
K˜G$#“ #c`##r#ãr !K˜GH! "K˜G  !K˜G°½ÀFô   Y*  m*  y  õ(  %)  µ (Ð  !K˜Gà  !K˜G½ÀF%)  E)  0µ‘°.L##p #cp£p©"Jp‹p
p )K˜G#xÙ    " )ÑZ  Ò&H!@!˜@aªp #S`“`tSt‘tÑtu$!ST   “
“€#[Ó`K“b#[BÓbKcKScK“aHIK˜G (ÑM,h K˜G#@#ƒ@K`*hÓi +üÑ"h#C#`K˜G K˜G   àú @²°0½¨  å*   D A      €–˜ ¬
```

The content descriptions above are just example information, not the actual bytes no be written, just theoretical context.

Just as any device out there, the main target is to write the IDs, frequencies, data, etc, in each one of the hardware devices.

I thought about a set of JSON files in local windows machine, that will read the content, in order to write it to the current device connected, and ready to be flashed (no fuse usage at this point).

So, that would be, something like, `Data_File_1.json`:

```
{
    'device_1_data' : {

        'device_uuid' : {
            'low_uuid' : '0x00000001',
            'high_uuid' : '0xABCD000A'
        },

        'key_1' : ['0x2E', '0x34', '0x72', '0x0A', '0x45', '0x57', '0x41', '0x17', '0x07', '0x52', '0xCA', '0x4C', '0x0D', '0x7B', '0x41', '0x57'],

        'module_data' : "0x387A3830",
        'frequency_0' : '390200000',
        'frequency_1' : '392100000',

        'generator_syncword' : '0xCF'

    }
}
```

The project reads specific memory addresses in order to get up and running, setting up the IDs and the information needed to work. So, making use of the information that the JSON files are holding, that data needs to be written as a binary file, in order to convert it to SREC, so it can be written into the main binary file at the memory address specified with srecord tools.

So it's configured to read the information as it is. You can notice that the JSON holds hex data, but the JSON holds data as text, so the hex strings, need to be treated as hex, and the integers, need to be converted to hex in order to be appropiately written as expected by the application made.

So, that would be something like, `Data_To_Be_Written_1.bin`:

```
00000000:   01 00 CD AB 0A 00 00 00 2E 34 72 0A 45 57 41 17  #..Í«.....4r.EWA.
00000010:   07 52 CA 4C 0D 7B 41 57 30 38 7A 38 C0 FA 41 17  #.RÊL.{AW08z8ÀúA.
00000020:   A0 F8 5E 17                                      #ø^.
```

Data above is taken from the JSON file, so, it's expected as that, so we can make it work with the SRecord tools in order to write that data at memory address of the main binary file holding the project that will make the hardware module work.

---

### Third edit (solution and summary):

Thanks a lot to everyone!

The answer of @AnsgarWiechers indeed shows what's needed to get the *.bin expected.

If we take the example of `Data_File_1.json`:

```
{
    'device_1_data' : {

        'device_uuid' : {
            'low_uuid' : '0x00000001',
            'high_uuid' : '0xABCD000A'
        },

        'key_1' : ['0x2E', '0x34', '0x72', '0x0A', '0x45', '0x57', '0x41', '0x17', '0x07', '0x52', '0xCA', '0x4C', '0x0D', '0x7B', '0x41', '0x57'],

        'module_data' : "0x387A3830",
        'frequency_0' : '390200000',
        'frequency_1' : '392100000',

        'generator_syncword' : '0xCF'

    }
}
```

We can proceed then to perform some operations in powershell as follows:

```
# JSON processing.
$json = Get-Content 'C:\<path to json file>\device_data.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now that we got the json object to work, we proceed to start taking the data.

First, fetch the UUID. and declare the byte array to be used concatenating the first byte values.

**BEWARE HERE, if you know a workaround here, or the best programming practice, that will be awesome, I'm starting with this, so, I came down to what is below by reading and coding on-the-go.**

```
# Process the whole UUID from the two JSON fields.

[int64] $device_uuid = [int64] ($json.device_1_data.device_uuid.low_uuid + (($json.device_1_data.device_uuid.high_uuid).split('x')[1]))

$device_uuid_byte_array = [BitConverter]::GetBytes($device_uuid)

# Final Byte array for first target address.

[byte[]] $final_byte_array = $device_uuid_byte_array
```

Above I took advantage of the BitConverter function usage with int values. First a String concat is made with the high and low address, you can notice the order of the concatenation, and is because the endianness processed by powershell, so, in order to get the bytes in the following order `01 00 CD AB 0A 00 00 00`, powershell needs the string like `"0x00000001ABCD0001"`, **not like** `0xABCD00100000001`.

Then it converts the value to an integer, the result of that is `7177306113`. And making use of the function:

`[BitConverter]::getBytes(7177306113)`

We can get the Byte value array of that. So it can get concatenated, or in this case, be the starting value of the byte array that will be at the content of the binary file.

Next up is concatenation of the key string byte array of the JSON.

```
# Now process the key byte array from JSON.
[int[]] $key_1_value = [int[]] $json.device_1_data.key_1
[byte[]] $key_1_byte_array = [byte[]][int[]]$key_1_value

$final_byte_array += $key_1_byte_array
```

Now, can proceed with the `module_data` JSON field.

```
[int64] $module_data = [int64] $json.device_1_data.module_data

$module_data_byte_array = [BitConverter]::GetBytes($module_data)

$final_byte_array += $module_data_byte_array
```

Then the frequencies:

```
[int] $frequency_0 = [int] $json.device_1_data.frequency_0
[byte[]]$frequency_0_byte_array = [BitConverter]::getBytes($frequency_0)
$final_byte_array += $frequency_0_byte_array

[int] $frequency_1 = [int] $json.device_1_data.frequency_1
[byte[]] $frequency_1_byte_array = [BitConverter]::getBytes($frequency_1)
$final_byte_array += $frequency_1_byte_array
```

Finally the syncword:

```
[int] $generator_syncword = [int] $json.device_1_data.generator_syncword

$syncword_byte_array = [BitConverter]::GetBytes($generator_syncword)

$final_byte_array += $syncword_byte_array
```

Once we have everything fetched and concatenated at the byte array we can perform a pipe operation to get a glimpse of what we're getting.

That would be this preliminar output at powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $final_byte_array | format-hex

               Ruta:

               00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

    00000000   01 00 CD AB 01 00 00 00 2E 34 72 0A 45 57 41 17  ..Í«.....4r.EWA.
    00000010   07 52 CA 4C 0D 7B 41 57 30 38 7A 38 C0 FA 41 17  .RÊL.{AW08z8ÀúA.
    00000020   A0 F8 5E 17 CF 00 00 00                           ø^.Ï...
```

Now we can send that byte array to a file with extension *.bin, but as the data is appropiatelly written in bytes, there will be no issues with further steps with SRecord tools.

```
# File storage
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('C:\<path desired to save>\input_file.bin', $final_byte_array)
```

Once we have the file, we can work with srec_cat.exe, for illustrative purposes, let's suppose we're working with **CMD** at certain directory location, in which srec_cat.exe is located, as well as the `input_file.bin` we've just created.

```
>srec_cat input_file.bin -binary -o srec_input_file.srec
```

If we open the file `srec_input_file.srec` it will show something like:

```
S0220000687474703A2F2F737265636F72642E736F75726365666F7267652E6E65742F1D
S12300000100CDAB010000002E34720A455741170752CA4C0D7B415730387A38C0FA4117D5
S10B0020A0F85E17CF000000F8
S5030002FA
```

Then, we can convert it again, with hex-dump in order to see if we get the same byte values we saw back then at powershell output:

```
>srec_cat srec_input_file.srec -o hex_input_file.bin -hex-dump
```

If we open `hex_input_file.bin`, we can see that:

```
00000000: 01 00 CD AB 01 00 00 00 2E 34 72 0A 45 57 41 17  #..M+.....4r.EWA.
00000010: 07 52 CA 4C 0D 7B 41 57 30 38 7A 38 C0 FA 41 17  #.RJL.{AW08z8@zA.
00000020: A0 F8 5E 17 CF 00 00 00                          # x^.O...
```

And we can use this file to concat it at the offset desire, let's say that we intend to write it from location `0x1A010`, we do something like:

```
>srec_cat srec_input_file.srec -offset 0x1A010 -o srec_input_file_offset.srec
```

And we get something like:

```
S0220000687474703A2F2F737265636F72642E736F75726365666F7267652E6E65742F1D
S22401A0100100CDAB010000002E34720A455741170752CA4C0D7B415730387A38C0FA411723
S20C01A030A0F85E17CF00000046
S5030002FA
```

Then we review it with:

```
>srec_cat srec_input_file_offset.srec -o hex_input_file_offset.bin -hex-dump
```

And open it to see:

```
0001A010: 01 00 CD AB 01 00 00 00 2E 34 72 0A 45 57 41 17  #..M+.....4r.EWA.
0001A020: 07 52 CA 4C 0D 7B 41 57 30 38 7A 38 C0 FA 41 17  #.RJL.{AW08z8@zA.
0001A030: A0 F8 5E 17 CF 00 00 00                          # x^.O...
```

After this, we fill with `0xFF` the empty bytes of the `srec_input_file_offset.srec`:

```
>srec_cat.exe srec_input_file_offset.srec -fill 0xFF 0x0001A030 0x0001A040 -output final_srec_input_file.srec
```

Finally, only append the `final_srec_input_file.srec` with the srec of the main bin file.

Let's suppose we didn't convert the `main_file.bin`:

```
>srec_cat main_file.bin -binary -o main_file.srec
```

Then we get everything together:

```
>srec_cat main_file.srec srec_input_file_offset.srec -o final_file.bin -binary
```

And that's about that. Thanks a lot again for everything. Feedback and suggestions are very welcome.

Kind regards.

Comment: What exactly do you consider a "binary type file"? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this for?

Comment: I need this to write some keys, id's and some data into a final *.bin file that is intended to be flashed into hardware devices.

I consider a binary type file as a *.bin file that srecord tools can work with.

Comment: Yes, either you know something about binary format windows doesn't directly display (like padding .bin extensions with 4 bytes?? or being multiples of 16 bytes??) and perhaps you can elaborate further. It helps somebody like me. Cause as far as I know .bin is exactly the same as any other file except it's labeled as a .bin... Hmm so maybe that is why the 4 bytes of zeros?

Comment: Just text or non-printable characters as well? Which encoding? How is the data structured?

Comment: You need to know memory layout for the device. Like flashing spi flash rom for an intel cpu, you need to know the flash memory mapping. Maybe 4kbytes is mapped to 0xfffffff0 for example. So you write to that offset. It's all just memory mapping. Also I think windows .bin has no relation to that format. Think one example is .spi for firmware. https://github.com/espressif/esptool/wiki/Firmware-Image-Format then there are images which format the data in out of order way that the flash programmer expects.

Comment: either way you need to provide more information.

Comment: I'll edit question to add more details.

Comment: Also some of the memory maps for flash sadly are often proprietary and not open to public. Why I have no idea. Working knowledge of a device shouldn't be a critical break in chain of trust but hey I don't work at intel.

Comment: ...not knowing what you are trying to accomplish, have you ever heard of [`CertUtil.exe`](http://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html)? it features two sub-commands `-encodehex` and `-decodehex` to convert text files to hex. dump files and vice versa...

Comment: Never heard or read about it, thanks for the hint. I'm checking that one out asap @aschipfl

Comment: You're welcome! it is available on Windows natively at least since Vista, as far as I can remember; just type e. g. `CertUtil -encodehex -?` to see the available options...

Comment: Tried CertUtil, with standard options and so with unicode. Named it with *.bin extension, but no effect. srec tools are still taking that *bin hex file, as text content file. But thanks a lot for letting us know about that utility @aschipfl.

Comment: It's very unlikely that anybody will be able to help you unless you specify what format/structure your "binary" input file is supposed to have.

Comment: Hmm... if your `output.bin` file is truly a binary file, `CertUtil -encodefile "output.bin" "output.hex"` would create a hex. dump file...

Comment: I see, the nature of file isn't a binary after all... Because I saved a text file with `hello_world` string, converted to hex-dump binary with `CertUtil`, but, I guess that's not the way to be used. I'm getting started with these things, sorry for the vague background. I'll try to keep up with you guys.

Comment: As far as I can make out, in order to work deductively and not just basically guess at who knows what, you need to know several things. You need to know exactly the device and architecture you are attempting to store firmware for, an arm atmel? You need to know the device which itself is storing the firmware, a spi flash rom, maybe bootloader area on the chip with bootloader pins straps? You need to know what the flash programmer expects as well if using one. For example I might use a computer with an spi io available and write to the flash rom. It's not clear thought what you are asking.

Comment: Hi @marshalcraft! Thanks for your interest in this topic. Indeed there are topics like bootloader, SPI, flash EEPROM via JTAG via USB, etc, but, that is already done. The source made from the IDE is appropiatelly set with the bootloader appended to it, and I have the addresses to which I'm supposed to write the data. I made a mistake in omitting information, but that was because thought It was not necessary to get into that depth of details, the main target is to write custom data to the main firmware binary (with tools ready to flash) that will be used among the few devices we're testing on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing data bytes to a file is simple enough. Get some data, transform it to a byte array, then write that array to a file:

```
$s = 'some text'
$b = [byte[]][char[]]$s
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('C:\path\to\output.bin', $b)
```

That won't help you any, though, if the bytes you're writing to the file aren't laid out correctly for whatever it is you're trying to do. In the above example you're still getting an ASCII text file despite the extension `.bin` (extensions are merely for associating a group of files with a particular program anyway).

---

**Edit:** Given the sample input and output data from your updated question you need to write integer values (in hexadecimal and decimal notation) as byte sequences with varying byte order and also align the data.

Here is an example to get you started:

```
function Get-Bytes([uint32]$val) {
  [BitConverter]::GetBytes($val)
}

$json  = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$bytes = @()

# convert UUID and append to byte array
$bytes += $json.device_1_data.device_uuid.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
  $v = Get-Bytes $_.Value
  if ($v[2] -ne 0 -or $v[3] -ne 0) {
    $v[2, 3, 0, 1]
  } else {
    $v[0, 1]
  }
}

# fill missing bytes with zero values to align next sequence
$bytes += [byte[]]0 * (8 - $bytes.Count)

# convert key_1 and append to byte array
$bytes += $json.device_1_data.key_1 | ForEach-Object { [byte][uint32]$_ }

...
...   # continue for the rest of the data, adjust byte order as required
...

[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('C:\path\to\output.bin', $bytes)
```

Comment: I'm actually working out data type conversion in order to write appropiatelly the information, so this will help indeed. The output file with a hardcoded byte array with use of `[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('C:\path\to\output.bin', $b)
` indeed works fine when working with Srecord tools. Now I know more about binary files, and how to write them. Will try the code posted at edit and come back later on. Thanks!

I'll try this up and will

Answer (score 3):

`certutil` can do both: create a hex (dump) file from a binary, and create a binary file from a hex coded file:

```
certutil -f -encodeHex out.bin out.txt >nul
certutil -f -decodeHex hex.txt out.bin >nul
```

To create a binary file from batch, see here: 
https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5326

For a decimal dump for a binary file:
`comp File1 File2 /D /m`
(similar to `gc -encoding byte File1` in powershell)

For hex dump of a binary file:
`fc /b File1 File2`
(similar to `gc -encoding byte File1 |% {write-host ("{0:X2}" -f $_)}` in powershell)

NB: File2 is a reference file with no similar characters to File1.
If unsure, then a workaround would be to fill File2 with 0x20, then for 2nd comparison fill File2 with 0x00 and replace the missing characters with 0x20 (in the 1st comparison)
*Hint:* **Check offset address.**

Tested on Win 10 x64

Comment: `certutil -encodeHex -v InFile OutFile` worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/man5/srec_binary.html) tells me:

> It is possible to read and write binary files using srec_cat(1).

(Having no personal experience with SRecord,) **I take this to mean that you can use your input file *as-is*, using its *raw bytes* - no need for hex dumps and reformatting**; you merely need to follow its filename on the command line with option `-binary`.

This assumes that your input file uses the desired character encoding; if not, convert it first, such as with `iconv`, or even a `Get-Content -Encoding ...` / `Set-Content -Encoding ...` combination.

The acceptable input formats are described [here](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/); format `Ascii-Hex` is *similar* to what `Format-Hex` produces, but would require non-trivial tweaking.

---

Generally, note that representations such as the ones created by `Format-Hex` are *themselves* invariably *text*, not "binary".
They describe a sequence of byte values *textually*, which allows them to *represent* arbitrary data, including binary (non-textual) data.

Comment: Certainly they're text.

Ok, so, I don't know how to write raw bytes into a binary file. The hex-dumps are only for visual reference, at the end we will be using solely the raw binary.

Cannot use `iconv`because we're using windows environment.

I'm documenting myself in order to see how can I use the `get-content... ` / `set-content` combo.

Tried to hardcode an ascii hex file with *.hex and *.bin extension, but the srec_cat tool doesn't recognize the content, so it ignores it.

Currently reading about everything you people are posting here, thanks a lot.

Comment: @GJntN That's why I keep telling you that you need to tell us **WHAT THE CONTENT OF THAT FILE NEEDS TO LOOK LIKE.**

Comment: @GJntN: Adding to Ansgar's comment: What is the source of these raw bytes, and why does that source need transforming?

Comment: I'll add another edit to add information you ask. Thanks a lot for the follow-up.